# Listview item smaller than screen width so the activity background is visible on the sides

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to know how to modify my list items layout so they don't fill the screen width and the activity background is visible on the sides.

I tried with various layout_width with no success.

I just want to know how to do it, the I'll apply the rule in my case

Edit: 
xml code of the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

android:clipToPadding="true"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/post_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_post" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_nick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/post_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight` on your ListView (in the XML) to set a minimum margin between the ListView and the screen sides.

Comment: Your XML doesn't contain a ListView - I suppose that it's the list row. You need to set the margin property on the ListView itself, not inside the row layout.

Comment: has no effects at all, I'm not using a custom layout in the listview using xml but i'm modifying it from code in createView()

Comment: Where is your ListView defined? NOT the rows, the ListView itself. It's displayed as a part of some screen layout, isn't it? That's where you need to put the margins.

Comment: i'm using a listfragment

Comment: So use a custom layout, and in your @android:id/list, add the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Use `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` (not margin) on your ListView.

```
     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:paddingRight="5dp"
       />
```